# expandable list is collapsing on refresh of UI

Tags: android

I have implemented the following code:

```
explistView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() { 
    public void onGroupCollapse(int id){  
        ExpandableListView expand=(ExpandableListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.explistview); 
        expand.expandGroup(id); 
    } 
});
```

still on UI Refresh the expandable list is collapsing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getGroupView` method like following

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    ExpandableListView eListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    eListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    return v;
}
```

I hope this will help you